# Access layout in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am using Laravel Layout. My folder and file structure is like below:

[image]

I am trying to access layout from dashboard.blade.php like below.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
  
@endsection
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Thanks @shaedrich. I am using `@yield('content')` inside `master.blade.php`. But other parts of the Template are not accessing.

Comment: can you show us the whole content of both master.blade.php and dashboard.blade.php?